# Is there a way to create a table with the names of all the stored procedures in a particular database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a database which has a store of procedures in that particular database. Is there a way anyone can make a table of the names of all the stored procedures as a table, instead of manually typing each one. How would I write the query? Is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? You have that data readily available already? select * from sys.procedures https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-procedures-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Or `SELECT name FROM` **[`Sys.Objects`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-objects-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** `WHERE Type = 'P';`

Answer (score 2):

Sean Lange is right you already have data in sys.procedures table. In case you still want to create a table:

```
SELECT * INTO [Table_Name] FROM sys.procedures
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to get the list of stored procedures

Here after 3 ways:
The last one is the old way, at the time of sql server 2000

```
select name,create_date,modify_date from sys.procedures 
select name,create_date,modify_date from sys.objects  where type='p'
select name,crdate,refdate from sysobjects where xtype='p'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want more information besides just the names you can pull that too.  For instance here is a query that pulls, the database, schema, procedure, definition, create date, and last modified date for all the stored procedures in a database.  You could combine this with a call to the sys.sp_MSforeachdb stored proc to create a table for each database on a server.

```
SELECT
    DB_NAME() AS [Database],
    s.name AS [Schema],
    p.name AS [Procedure],
    ISNULL(d.definition,'***ENCRYPTED PROCEDURE***') AS [Definition],
    p.create_date,
    p.modify_date
INTO [Table_Name]
FROM sys.procedures AS p
JOIN sys.sql_modules AS d on p.object_id = d.object_id
JOIN sys.schemas AS s on p.schema_id = s.schema_id
```